# I want to write trigger for restricing numeric values insertion

Tags: mysql, constraints, database-trigger, check-constraints

I want to write trigger for restricting user to insert numeric values and special characters in Name field of column.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_check BEFORE
     INSERT ON tempuser
     FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     IF :new.firstname NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
     THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('INSERT ONLY ALPHABETS');
     END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: A check constraint would be a much better choice

Comment: @Ajay in a comment you mentioned *mysql and phpmyadmin*. You should tag your question with the correct products you're using. This will help you get a timely answer and also prevents people wasting their time writing responses which don't help you.

Answer (score 1):

*As @a_horse_with_no_name pointed out, better to add a check constraint like the one below :*

```
alter table TAB
  add constraint CHK_NAME_WITHOUT_NUMBER
  check (not regexp_like(name,'[0-9]+'));
```

*of course after clearing the data which contain numbers. To accomplish this aim, the following `DML` statement may be used before the above `DDL` :*

```
update tab
   set name = regexp_replace(name,'[0-9]+','');
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I have already tried check constraint but it doesn't working with mysql and phpmyadmin

Comment: @Ajay you're welcome, but question is tagged with `Oracle`, not `MySQL`. I looked that you didn't tag as that but `plsql` already implies `Oracle`.